# For normalization purposes what is the best way of relating these tables? 2 relations to an entity vs 1 to another entity

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, database-normalization

Please bear with me I am still pretty new to databases and SQL. I am working on a project outside of school to make for an entry level portfolio. It's a relational database for Pokemon TCG tournament results to card data and prices. I created a series of relationship diagrams that I have been slowly evolving as I scrape the needed data and implement them in tables for the project, realizing things like "I don't need this here because it can be inferred by this relationships".

However for one of my entity relationships I wanted to relate a the entities of a specific deck to the cards in the deck. A deck has many cards and a card can be in many decks. To represent that I needed an associative table. Which I called DeckCards. That being said, in the card game a deck has two primary cards that kind of define the deck, which I wanted to relate to card set. Basically if a card set has a lot of key cards in a lot of decks, it shows that it is a very good set and should have a higher price.

At first I originally made an associative table thinking, "OK a deck has up to two sets that its key cards are in, and a set can define the key cards of multiple decks.
[image]

But that didn't seem right. Even playing around with which entity got the key cards didn't seem nothing really fitr. I thought maybe a relationship right to the Set entity might work, but then I would lose information about what the actual card is.

So I googled if I could have multiple relationships between entities and apparently I could. Then the logic would be: A deck has a key card 1 with a card ID X and a key card 2 with a card ID Y. The cards I can then relate to their set ids and such. Can I have multiple foreign keys to the same primary key in the same table? Does my other associative table hurt my logic?

So now I have this. Which might be right? But I wanted to ask you guys what might be better or if I am doing anything right at all.
[image]

I really appreciate any advice in advance. If you see me being wrong anywhere else I would love to hear it.

Comment: Are the "key cards" also part of "deck card", in other words: are all "Cards" which relate to a "Set" which in turn relates to a particular "Deck" also part of "DeckCards" for the same "Deck"?

Comment: If I am reading this correctly I think this is the correct answer to the question. Two of the cards in the list of deck cards are the key cards.

Comment: Ohh, maybe you are hinting at I should have key cards in the DeckCard entity? If that is the case I would need another column identifying if a card was a key card or not with that particular deck id!

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think either of these options are correct.**

I think you have two options:

- Either add a column to `DeckCards` and have a filtered unique index on that.

```sql
CREATE TABLE KeyDeckCard (
    DeckId int,
    CardId int,
    IsKey BIT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (DeckId, CardId)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_DeckKey (DeckId) INCLUDE (IsKey) WHERE IsKey = 1;
```

- Or better: a **separate table** of `KeyDeckCard` which has exactly the same two columns as `DeckCards`, both primary key, and foreign keyed to `DeckCard`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE KeyDeckCard (
    DeckId int,
    CardId int,
    PRIMARY KEY (DeckId, CardId),
    FOREIGN KEY (DeckId, CardId) REFERENCES DeckCard (DeckId, CardId)
)
```